# In getorgchart jquery plugin how to remove the getorgchart hyperlink present at the bottom of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, jquery-plugins, getorgchart

I am trying to use getorgchart jquery plugin. And I want to remove the 'GetOrgChart' hyprlink which is showing in the bottom of the screen.  I have tried removing it from getorgchart.js file but it is still showing up. Is it part of the theme? How Can I stop showig it on my webpage???

Please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, It worked for me.

Add following code in your html page.

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {

    setInterval(function(){ $('a[title="GetOrgChart jquery plugin"]').hide(); }, 10);

 });
```

Comment: Link is not permanently hide it blinks after a random time what ever you mention in function , this is an incomplete solution.I want to hide it permanently even on page load it should not show for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Try This,

In your orgchart.html page, paste this snippet

```
<div style="display: block; position: absolute; bottom: 15px; right: 0;z-index: 214748336480 !important; height: 25px; width: 100px; background: #333;"></div>
```

Change width, height and background to your liking. But make sure z-index is higher than what I have mentioned, this is the important point here. Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: Div comes over the link and i give div background colour what i want so basically it hides the link. it works for me thanks buddy.

Answer (score 2):

Open file `getorgchart.js` and find `eval(eval("String.fromCharCode(blah3x...)"))`
and delete it or comment.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the getorgchart logo you need to buy a license http://www.getorgchart.com/Buy

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to temporarily disable `eval()`, which GetOrgChart uses to keep the logo on display:

```
<script>__eval__ = eval; eval = function () { };</script>
<script src="getorgchart.js"></script>
<script>eval = __eval__;</script>
```